# Book about a young boy who gets captured and tortured with his best friend

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember that he gets beaten up pretty early into the book. At one point he and his friend are playing with a red ball and they kick it over a barbed wire fence into a compound.

Later on they are captured, tortured and starved. It ends with them kissing each other then possibly dying.
I've been looking for this book everywhere.

Comment: Sounds charming.  Also doesn't sound like science fiction or fantasy; can you expand on those aspects of the story?

Comment: Please try to add more detail to this question. When did you read it? How old was the book? How long was it (novel or short story)? Was it in English? Where was it set? How old are these boys? Take a look at the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394) and see if anything jogs your memory. Most importantly, **what were the sci-fi or fantasy elements of the story?** It's not quite clear from your description, but if it wasn't a sci-fi/fantasy book, you might consider posting at [literature.se] SE instead.

Comment: It actually sounds like a "mis-remembered" variation of the boy in the striped pyjamas..